# Cinderella vs. GeoGebra

Tags: geometry, software

I would be grateful for a comparison between 
the capabilities of [Cinderella](https://www.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php) and
[Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/), for teaching
at all levels, but especially at the college/university-level.
I became a reasonably adept user of Cinderella,
but have only dabbled in GeoGebra.

Here is my naive, nonexpert sense of where matters might stand:

> Cinderella is more mathematically sophisticated, but
>   now less actively supported, and with a smaller user base than GeoGebra. So it might be wise, pragmatically, to "switch" to GeoGebra.

To support my sense that "Cinderella is more mathematically sophisticated":

[The Cinderella Manual](https://books.google.com/books?id=y7Ori_ehpLUC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=cinderella+and+complex+numbers&source=bl&ots=jjDxzAtZ7y&sig=ACfU3U34SagOUF2wvULRH8cUJdquqVTBHw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAmJWT2IvmAhURd98KHSbuBicQ6AEwC3oECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=cinderella%20and%20complex%20numbers&f=false):

> "Cinderella's mathematical kernel is implemented entirely over the complex numbers"

[GeoGebra manual](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Complex_Numbers):

> "GeoGebra does not support complex numbers directly"

Comment: I cannot compare any of these things, including the thing I'm about to introduce: *Mathematica 12* can now handle [axiomatic geometry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SyntheticGeometry.html) in that you can enter hypotheses, it will solve the constraints to construct a geometric "scene" satisfying the hypotheses, and it can search for conjectures about what follows from the hypotheses. User-input syntax is also more "sophisticated," that is, difficult for students to pick up easily.

Comment: @user1527: Licenses for Mathematica are expensive and most institutions, particularly outside the US, do not have access to such tools.

Answer (score 3):

As you say - GeoGebra is still actively developed. For example we've just added support for complex functions

http://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:Changelog_6.0

Comment: I think it would be better if you explicitly disclosed in your answer that you are the lead developer of GeoGebra.

Comment: I agree with @JoelReyesNoche about mentioning your affiliation. Moreover, I think it would be helpful to add some more explanation. What will we find in that link? How does it address the main questions in the original post? (As it is now, this feels more like a *comment* than an *answer*.)